# Core data - How to reload NSSet (child objects) on second tableview controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

Hi I am new to Core data. I am having difficulties in reloading my child objects or the NSSet objects which is located on a second tableview.

So I have two tableview controllers, the first one is Budget where I can add or delete a budget. Within that budget object it has a one to many relationship with Expense object (So the Expense is the NSSet).

After when I tap into one of the budget cells, it takes me to the NSSet of Expenses, I then converted the Expenses NSSet into NSArray by using the allObjects method like below:

```
_expenses = [[_currentBudget expenses]allObjects];
```

I then populated the table view controller and it shows me all of the individual expense available within that budget. I then have an add (+) bar button to add an expense into the current budget (or call the predefined method that core data gave me: `-(void)addExpensesObject(NSManagedObject*)object`

Everything is great and it can be saved. However.... once I saved I am not sure how to reload the NSArray of expenses as it is not like the fetchedResultsController. (I am able to reload data on the first tablview once a budget was added because i used the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and implemented the changes/update/insert etc methods).

So my question is, how do I reload those set of NSArray objects? I tried to add in viewdidappear `[[self tableview]reloadData]` but that didn't work for some reason.. But when I tap back to the first tableview (budgets) and tap back into the expense... it reloads.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to use a fetched results controller in the
second table view controller as well. Instead of passing

```
[[_currentBudget expenses]allObjects]
```

to the second view controller, just pass `_currentBudget`. In the second view
controller, create a fetched results controller with a 
fetch request on the "Expense" entity and using a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"budget = %@", self.currentBudget]
```

Comment: Hi Thank for your help. So I did what you said, passed in the currentBudget and fetch with NSpredicate to get that exact same object. I then get the budget's expense (NSSet) and put it into an array object using the allObjects method as the tableview controller needs indexes. Then i implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and implemented the controller didChangeObject with one of the case: NSNSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

Comment: CODE: Expense *changedExpense = [_expenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView]cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [[cell textLabel]setText:[changedExpense expenseName]];

Comment: it still not updating the tableview :(

Comment: @jonprasetyo: Why don't you use the "boiler-plate" fetched results controller code as show in the NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate documentation?

Comment: Just figured it out, I miss understood your first reply, Thank you!